# How to get json data from other domain?

Tags: xmlhttprequest

I am working in an Angular app. I need to get a Json from the following url:

http://www.citibikenyc.com/stations/json

I tried using `$http.get()` and `$http.jsonp()`

When I do the following

```
$http.get("http://www.citibikenyc.com/stations/json")
        .then(function (response) {
           console.log(response.data);
        });
```

I am getting the following error :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load [url that i use here]. 
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. 
Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
```

When I do the following code:

```
$http.jsonp("http://www.citibikenyc.com/stations/json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK")
       .then(function (response) {
          console.log(response.data);
       });
```

I am getting `SyntaxError: Unexpected token :`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the service/API you are trying to call doesn't allow you. What you are trying to do is cross-side scripting and is not allowed unless there is a CORS policy on the service that allows your domain. "http://localhost" is not a valid domain for this service.